# *React-table* second page not showing data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-table

I have a table which displays clinics. I have also a onPageChange prop which handles the pageIndex and then i fetch the data based on that page. Below is my table configuration

```
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ClinicFormComponent from './newClinicForm';
import SearchFormComponent from '../search/searchForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchClinics, fetchClinic, deleteClinic, searchClinics, pushBreadcrumb, popBreadcrumb } from '../../actions/index.js';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import store from '../../helpers/store';
import { ic_search } from 'react-icons-kit/md/ic_search';
import SvgIcon from 'react-icons-kit';
require('normalize.css/normalize.css');
// require('styles/App.css');

class ClinicsPage extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClickForm = this.handleClickForm.bind(this);
    this.handleClickFormSearch = this.handleClickFormSearch.bind(this);
    this.closeForm = this.closeForm.bind(this);
    this.onPageChange = this.onPageChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.searchClinics({ country: 'Australia' });
  }

  onPageChange(pageIndex) {
      this.props.fetchClinics(pageIndex, null);
  }

  render() {
    let { devs } = this.props;

    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Id',
        accessor: 'id' // String-based value accessors!
      }, {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name'
      }, {
        Header: 'Description', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'description',
        sortable: true
        // accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      },
      {
        Header: 'Country', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'country',
        sortable: true
        // accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      },
      {
        Header: 'Area', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'area',
        sortable: true
        // accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      },
      {
        Header: 'Latitude', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'latitude',
        sortable: true
        // accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      },
      {
        Header: 'Longitude', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'longitude',
        sortable: true
        // accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      },
      {
        Header: 'Tags', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        accessor: 'tags',
        sortable: true,
        Cell: (row) => {if (row.original.tags.length>1) { return row.original.tags.join(', ') } else { return row.original.tags } }
      },
      {
        Header: () => <span className="text-center">Actions</span>,
        accessor: 'id',
        id: 'actions',
        sortable: true,
        Cell: (row) => (<span><button className="text-center btn btn-primary-zoetis margin_right_5" onClick={()=>{this.props.history.push('/editClinic/'+ row.original.id)}}>Edit</button ><button className="text-center btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>{this.props.deleteClinic(row.original.id, row.original)}}>Delete</button ></span>)
      }
    ]

    return (
      <div className="wrap">
          <div className="row margin_top_10 margin_bottom_5">
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <a className="btn btn-link color_zoetis btn_zoetis_alt" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2" onClick={this.handleClickForm}>NEW CLINIC</a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <a className="nav-link float_right search-clinic-btn" data-toggle="collapse" onClick={this.handleClickFormSearch} role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span className="search_label">Search data entries...</span> <SvgIcon size={25} icon={ic_search}/></a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="nav-tabContent">
            <ReactTable
              data={devs.clinics}
              pageSizeOptions= {[10]}
              defaultPageSize= {10}
              columns={columns}
              pages={devs.paginationData.totalPages || ''}
              sortable={true}
              multiSort={true}
              //manual
              filterable
              page={devs.paginationData.pageNumber}
              loading={devs.isFetching}
              onPageChange={this.onPageChange}
              noDataText='No Data Found'
              className='-striped -highlight'
              />
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    devs: state.reducer.devs,
    showMenu: state.reducer.devs.showMenu,
    showEditMenu: state.reducer.devs.showEditMenu,
    paginationData: state.reducer.devs.paginationData,
    location: state.router.location.pathname
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchClinics,
  searchClinics,
  fetchClinic,
  deleteClinic,
  pushBreadcrumb,
  popBreadcrumb
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClinicsPage);
```

Notice that i have disabled manual prop. If i enable the manual prop then i can navigate through next and previous pages but i cannot sort or filter the data.

With the manual prop disabled the filtering and the sorting works correct but when i navigate in the next page the table is showing empty. The first page displays correct the first 10 data. Also i have tested the api and returns correct the next 10 data.

Is there any workaround? To keep both server side pagination and alse the default sorting and filtering?

Comment: Can you post the entire component? Hard to tell what's going on just looking at the react table. Can you confirm that when the onPageChange function is triggered, the `devs.paginationData.pageNumber` is being updated and the component is rerendering as expected?

Comment: @erichardson30 i have updated my answer

Comment: also the devs.paginationData.pageNumber is updated correctly, and the page is changing with the correctly page number on the table

Answer (score 4):

Test decomposing manual property

```
    <ReactTable
      filtered={this.state.filtered}
      onFilteredChange={this.onFilteredChange.bind(this)}
      defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
        String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value
      }
      columns={columns}
      ref={r => (this.selectTable = r)}
      className="-striped -highlight"
      defaultPageSize={10}
      data={this.state.data}
      pages={this.state.pages}
      loading={this.state.loading}
      manual <-------
      resizable={true}
      filterable
      filterAll={true}
      onFetchData={(state, instance) => {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        axios.get(`${API}${controller}`, {
          params: {
            pages: state.page,
            pageSize: state.pageSize,
            filtered: state.filtered,
            typeOption: `${type}`,
            dateinit: `${this.state.dateinit}`,
            datefinal: `${this.state.datefinal}`,
            data: this.props.data
          },
          headers: { 'Authorization': `${tokenCopyPaste()}` }
        })
          .then((res) => {
            this.props.exportTable(res.data, type);
            this.setState({
              data: res.data.data,
              fulldata: res.data,
              pages: Math.ceil(res.data.pages / state.pageSize),
              loading: false
            })
          })
      }
      }
    />
```

Comment: Shouldnt line near the end be:                                                                                      pages: Math.ceil(res.data.length / state.pageSize)?